# Webview upload file from camera don't work

Tags: android, file-upload, upload, android-webview

i have app that load website in webview where have login form and after login user can to send photos from this html form. After select inupt="file" can select from storage or make photo. In selection from storage work fine but when select make photo with camera - open and make photo and after that attached, but when i try to get it from the form with FileReader (in xxx.onload = function(){}) don't return nothings, any idea why?

Thank you so much!